# How can i go throuth all records in sql using one button depending on date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a qquestion regarding to vba Access .
I have a form that show record depending on query.
I want to create button so by click on it i can go to the previous record that which has previous date but with same fk id .so how can i do that

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is going to be a fun post for me. This is a pretty common thing you might want done. Also, this should be a comment, however, clearly the text length is way too long for a comment.

So first things first youre going to need to know how to do the following:

- Learn about controls events, how to access them and add them.
- Learn how sub forms work and how to update their contents. This actually has a bunch of sub tasks you will need to learn to figure this out, and there are multiple different ways to go about it.

  1. Learn what record sources and row sources are and how to edit them in the UI and then via code.
  2. Figure out what the differences between form.Refresh, form.repaint and form.requery are. Form.Requery is what youre going to want to learn for this particular exercise.
  3. Learn how to correctly references forms and their subforms. This ill be a particular headache if you dont get out in front of it ahead of time. Its not difficult but some people sometime shave issues with it.
  4. Learn how to bind queries to forms and the bind specific columns to controls on subforms
- Learn how to bind queries predicates (where clause/filter) to control values. This can be done in the UI, but I find it is easier to do in code since Im a SQL Dev first, access guy second. This seems likes its in two spots, but the topic of setting the definition of a presaved query is a topic on its own and very much worth knowing how to do. Youll end up needing to research QueryDefs and how to edit them.
- And Finally to your specific scenario about paging - what your describing is a technique called paging. Some languages have "things" ready to handle this but since we're in Access/VBA land, you might need to get creative. Ive seen people use make table queries where they mimic ROW_NUMBER() functions from sql server to enforce a unique auto incrementing PK (primary key) so that paging logic is super easy. Ive also seen hack-ish ways of storing unique identifiers in hidden controls (ew gross) for this purpose as well. This is the part where you get to flex that awesome brain of yours and figure it out from there - by the time youve learn all this stuff, I feel like youll be able to do so easily.

Happy coding!